# Parametrize solution

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Consider the matrix
>   $$G=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-2&1&0\\
> 0&0&1&-2&0\\
> 0&0&0&1&-2\\
> 0&0&0&0&0\\
> 0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$G\begin{bmatrix}v\\w\\x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
By which sets of variables can $V$ be parametrised?

My attempt at a solution was to find the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix, which I found to be:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1&2&0&0&-6&6\\
0&0&1&0&-4&3\\
0&0&0&1&-2&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$
Written as a system of equations, we have:
$$v+2w-6z=6$$
$$x-4z=3$$
$$y-2z=1$$
Thus I determined the sets of variables able to parametrize the solution space to be:

$vxy$ (x can be anything, y anything), $wxy$ (x can be anything, y can be anything), $zxy$ (x anything, y anything), $xvwy$ (v, w, and y can be anything), $zvwy$ (v, w, and y can be anything), and $zxvw$ (x, v, and w can by anything).

Thus my answer is: $vxy$, $wxy$, $zxy$, $xvwy$, $zvwy$, $zxvw$. Is this correct or am I totally incorrect in my thinking? Thank you.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format mathematical expressions instead of pasting in images. They are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor does this key content of your question show up in summaries. You can find a MathJax quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?s=5|36.4843). For the little few expressions that you have above, I have to imagine that it took at least as long to crop the images, upload them and link to them as it would have to type them in.

Comment: Sorry I tried to use MathJax for the system of equations, I just didn't how to use it to create matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking and answer are wrong. Rather:

- If $z$ is a parameter, it determines $x,y$.
- If $z$ is not a parameter, one of $x,y$ can be a parameter, determining $z$ and hence the non-parameter in $x,y$.
- Either way, we may choose one of $v,w$ as parameter, and this determines the other.

Thus the variable sets that parametrise $V$ are $vz,wz,xv,xw,yv,yw$. All these have cardinality 2, consistent with $G$'s nullity being 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm pretty confused, I don't understand why we may choose one of v,w as a parameter, and this determines the other?

Comment: I get the first and second bullet points but not the third.

Comment: So do we not z has a parameter because it only determines x and y? on the other hand v determines z which determines x and y, likewise for w, thats why we choose these two as parameters?

Comment: @kemb Any one of $x,y,z$ will determine the other two. Given that these have been parametrised, any one of $v,w$ wil determine the other with the help of (the determined) $z$.

Comment: Ok got it.  So we choose v and w as parameters because can determine either one can determine the other with the help of z? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Great, just did.